# Who proposed the bulk-edge correspondence principle?

Tags: soft-question, history, topological-insulators, holographic-principle

Who proposed the [bulk-edge correspondence principle](http://www.google.de/search?q=bulk+edge+correspondence)?

The principle is often quoted in counting the number of zero energy states localized on the interface between two insulators with distinct band topology. However, I could not retrieve who was the first to say that.

Comment: I edited your second question out of the post, because we prefer to have one question per post. But feel free to post it separately. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it was Xiao-Gang Wen in 1989, see also this 1994 paper by him and his collaborators

> http://dao.mit.edu/~wen/pub/ednab.pdf

He's at MIT. I was once hosting a seminar by him, he is one of the most creative and playful folks in this segment of condensed matter physics. The paper above contains some other relevant references, including a paper by Wen and Tony Zee.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out that nice article for me !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is R. Jackiw and C. Rebbi (Phys. Rev. D 13, 3398)

When explaining the quantum Hall effect, Hasan and Kane (Rev. Mod.Phys. 2010, 82: 3045–3067) said "This interplay between topology and gapless modes is ubiquitous in physics and has appeared in many contexts. It was originally found by **Jackiw and Rebbi (1976)** in their analysis of a 1D field theory" in pages 3048-3049.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. I also learned this when reading Jackiw's Dirac prize lecture. However, he did not in that work propose the principle and there was no topological argument therein.

Answer (score 0):

@Hai-Yao Deng. I hope that by now you might have found the answer to your question. I have recently started reading about the topological phases of matter. I find that in his paper, Y. Hatugai PRB 48, 1993 study in detail about this correspondence for the integer quantum Hall effect. He also summaries a sort of development of the argument from TKNN calculation of Hall conductance to the numerical computation of edge states in the same system by Rammal, Toulouse, Jaekel, and Halperin.